# Using jMesa from php

Tags: php, mysql, jmesa

That's my first question because I'm new programming, and maybe it's a very stupid question but... Can I use jMesa for showing a mysql table with php? Can somebody give me a little first steps?

Thanks!

Comment: Show your effort budy...

Comment: yes, you can!! Go for it and if you have any trouble, post your issue here, show us your code and help us to help you :)